# What machine learning algorithms for process optimization

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I found a lot of articles talking about manufacturing process optimization using ML but I could not find detailed methodology with state-of-the-art algorithms to use for this. Classical ML algorithms are meant to predict while process optimization are about explaining data. To do so, I found ways to retro-engineer models to find correlations such as importance plot, SHAP and so on. This approach works but with high effort to format results in an understandable way for non-data scientists.

My willing would be to have an algorithm able to find the best process windows (intervals for KPP - key process parameters) to optimize a given KPI - key process indicator. For example "quality is x% better if your process is running with parameter A between x and y and parameter B above z". Of course, the algorithm would have to penalize rule's complexity (a rule based on 1 parameter is better than a rule based on 2) and lack of representativeness (a rule with 30% of my data inside the window is better than one with only 3%).

Is this approach the good one?

Does such algorithms exists (open source if possible) or should it be developed from scratch?

Would you have any other approach/algorithm in mind for process optimization?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! By process optimization, do you mean that you want the machine learning to determine actions to take in order to have the optimal outcome (with an "optimal" outcome define in some way, perhaps the shortest time or greatest profit)? If so, you might be interested in the tools of reinforcement learning and recommendation systems.